# Azure Ad roles and groups Claims in JWT not available in .NetCore WebApi

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.1

I hope you can help me with the following, as I've been looking for solutions everywhere but unfortunately have not been able to find anything that works. In short: I can see claims for groups and roles in the payload of the JWT in the browser, but they are not available for use in my .Net Core WebApi.

We have an application running as two Azure app services: a web app in Angular5 and a WebApi in .net core 2.1. We use Azure AD for authentication which works fine, and would now also like to use it for authorization based on either groups or roles.

In the web app we use the angular-oauth2-oidc library with the implicit flow.

In Azure I have set the  "groupMembershipClaims" to "All" and have created a role in the app manifest of the web app and assigned users to it. When I look in the payload of the JWT in the browser I do see the claims for roles and groups:

```
    {
      "aud": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/",
      "iat": xxxxxxxxxx,
      "nbf": xxxxxxxxxx,
      "exp": xxxxxxxxxx,
      "aio": "xxx"
      "amr": [
        "pwd"
      ],
      "at_hash": "xx"
      "family_name": "xxx"
      "given_name": "xxx",
      "groups": [
        "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
      ],
      "ipaddr": "xxx.xxx.xx.x",
      "name": "x",
      "nonce": "x",
      "oid": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "roles": [
        "xxxUser"
      ],
      "sub": "xxx",
      "tid": "xxx",
      "unique_name": "xxx",
      "upn": "xxx",
      "uti": "xxx",
      "ver": "1.0"
    }
```

However, when I want to use the roles or groups in my WebApi, the ClaimsPrincipal does not have the claims:
[Claims in WebApi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCqIW.png).

Initially I wanted to authorize on "sub" which was also missing, based on this blogpost: https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/ I used:

```
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

and/or

```
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("sub");
```

which worked to get the sub available, but this does not seem to work for roles or groups.

The code in my Startup.cs is as follows:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Authority").Value;
            options.Audience = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Audience").Value;
        });
```

I have been experimenting with various TokenValidationParameters to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I have the same problem where I am using Postman to generate an access token via  Authorization Code.  I need to be able to add "groups" claims to the token, but have not figured how how to do this or another workaround.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I ended up giving access to specific people which was OK as the user group is really small. But I'm still very curious as to how this should be solved!